# Select 2 specific lines from a table in database

Tags: mysql, sql, content-management-system, e-commerce

For the sake of comparison between two specific lines in a MySQL database, I need to show them one above the other.

I do the select based on a field (product_id). To retrieve one line I use:

> SELECT * FROM `ps_product` WHERE id_product=44

I need to have also the line for the product with id=29.

I tried :

> SELECT * FROM `ps_product` WHERE id_product=44 AND id_product=29

But it is not working.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `or` instead of `and`.  Or better yet:  `id_product in (44, 29)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Thank you very much. I feel this is it. Waiting for this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM ps_product WHERE id_product=44 OR id_product=29
```

This is the correct syntax.

Comment: He got no problems with syntax, logic was the problem.

Comment: @Notulysses. exactly, but you should not forget that e-commerce CMS users are not all logic/developpers. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @whiteletters and blankspaces : I mean that Onur Göker's conclusion after the query is a bit clumsy.

Comment: @Notulysses, I don't totally agree with the word 'clumsy', but I think on the fact that this answer should be a bit more detailed. I suggest Onur edit it explaining a few more. He can also add the suggestion by Gordon Linoff : id_product in (44, 29). Thanks everybody